# Completing install of ruby 1.9.3 with Ruby for for Mac OS X 10.7.5 Leopard, Xcode 4.5.2 -- problems with rvm pkg install openssl

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm, homebrew

First, many thanks in advance for any help.  I'm a complete novice with programming and I'm trying to get started with this Ruby on Rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2)

I have been trying figure this out for about 7 hours now and since I don't have any hair left to pull out I'm turning to these hallowed pages.  I have searched for solutions here again and again.

System: Mac OS X 10.7.5 Leopard, Xcode 4.5.2

I installed homebrew and have updated it multiple times
I used homebrew to install rvm and have updated it multiple times
I installed git

The standard ruby on the system (checking with $ ruby -v) is 1.8.7

My problem is that every time I try to use rvm to install a new version of Ruby ($ rvm install 1.9.3) I get the following error:

```
Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.
Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below.
Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.

  Notes for Mac OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

    rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
    rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

:
```

I have performed $ brew install libksba and when I try to do it again it tells me that libksba is installed already.

When I type "$ rvm requirements" I get:

```
      Notes for Mac OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

    rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
    rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

Right now Ruby requires gcc to compile, but Xcode 4.2 and later no longer ship with gcc. Instead they ship with llvm-gcc (to which gcc is a symlink) and clang, neither of which are supported for building Ruby. Xcode 4.1 was the last version to ship gcc, which was /usr/bin/gcc-4.2.

Xcode 4.1 and earlier:
- Ruby will build fine.

Xcode 4.2 and later (including Command Line Tools for Xcode):
- If you have gcc-4.2 (and friends) from an earlier Xcode version, Ruby will build fine.
- If you don't have gcc-4.2, you have two options to get it:
 * Install apple-gcc42 from Homebrew
 * Install osx-gcc-installer

  Homebrew:

  If you are using Homebrew, you can install the apple-gcc42 and required libraries from homebrew/dupes:

      brew update
      brew tap homebrew/dupes
      brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
      rvm pkg install openssl

  Xcode 4.2+ install or/and Command Line Tools for Xcode is required to provide make and other tools.

  osx-gcc-installer:

  If you don't use Homebrew, you can download and install osx-gcc-installer: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer.

  Warning: Installing osx-gcc-installer on top of a recent Xcode is known to cause problems, so you must uninstall Xcode before installing osx-gcc-installer. Afterwards you may install Xcode 4.2+ or Command Line Tools for Xcode if you desire.

  ** NOTE: Currently, Node.js is having issues building with osx-gcc-installer. The only fix is to install Xcode over osx-gcc-installer.
```

So I assume I have to do something with 
          brew update
          brew tap homebrew/dupes
          brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
          rvm pkg install openssl

Everything seemed to work fine until "$ rvm pkg install openssl", which returns:

```
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/openssl/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/openssl.certs.log
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ thierinvestmentservices$ rvm pkg install openssl
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/openssl/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/openssl.certs.log
```

make.log reads

```
"[2012-11-23 13:15:28] make
/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 116: make: command not found"
```

and openssl.certs.log reads

```
"[2012-11-23 14:04:04] update_openssl_certs
update_openssl_certs () 
{ 
    ( chpwd_functions="" builtin cd $rvm_usr_path/ssl && command curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem && mv cacert.pem cert.pem )
}
current path: /Users/thierinvestmentservices
command(1): update_openssl_certs
/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/functions/pkg: line 205: cd: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/usr/ssl: No such file or directory"
```

At this point the letters might as well be wingdings I have no idea what is going on.  I have tried to install rvm make with something I saw on one forum post but I got a bunch of warnings.  If anyone has any suggestions I would be deeply grateful, I am completely in over my head.

---

Per suggestion below, I tried to reinstall rvm.  Typing "rvm reinstall all --force" didn't do anything (it just gave me a new terminal line).  So I did a search and used rvm implode and then reinstalled per https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ Got the following message out of the rvm install:

.....

```
Error running '__rvm_package extract /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/src', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/extract.log
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
tee: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log: Permission denied
/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 116: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log: Permission denied
Error running '/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/fetch http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2', please read /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
ruby-1.9.3-p327 is not installed.
Creating alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Recording alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Creating default links/files
ruby-1.9.3-p327 is not installed.
Could not load ruby ruby-1.9.3-p327.
/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/alias: line 111: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

  * To start using rails you need to run `rails new <project_dir>`.
```

rvm install 1.9.3 gets me to the same place as before:

```
Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.
Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below.
Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.

  Notes for Mac OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

    rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
    rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

:
```

rvm requirements and rvm pkg install openssl also get me to the same exact place.  Best, J

Comment: did you perform rvm reinstall all --force ?

Comment: typing rvm reinstall all --force didn't do anything (it just gave me a new terminal line).  So I did a search and used rvm implode and then reinstalled per https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ results posted as edit above

Comment: it seems that you have a rights problem: tee: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log: Permission denied
/Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 116: /Users/thierinvestmentservices/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log: Permission denied - did you try to do all this as sudo user?

Comment: When I finally got the Xcode command line tools installed, I had to do sudo rvm install 1.9.3.  Is there any way I can make this sudo user status automatic?

Comment: ah - yes - that's waht did not come into my mind ;-) perfect! credits to @mpapis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Xcode you need to install command line tools, but ... easier way is to install osx-gcc-installer, it includes all the required libraries, compiler and is just one package

Comment: You are a godsend mpapis!  I did Xcode>preferences>dowloads>command line tools!  Then went back to the "$ rvm pkg install openssl" which finally worked and then sudo $ rvm install 1.9.3 worked.  I'm off and running with the tutorial.  I was completely stumped and you fixed it.  Hopefully someday I'll be able to help someone out here as much as you helped me.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to:

http://connect.apple.com

to get the latest Command Line Tools straight from Apple.  If you're using Homebrew, you may want to install Xcode fully as Homebrew recommends so.